# How do you conditionally render a React Native FlatList depending on the contents of the array?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have an array `completedTests` in my app, with one example of its contents being this (when I use `console.log()`):

```
Array [
  Object {
    "difference": 140,
    "id": "Practice Test 3",
    "targetReached": false,
    "testScore": "1400",
  }
]
```

To display its contents I would use:

```
<View>
<FlatList
    data={completedTests}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
           <View style={[styles.scoreOverview, { backgroundColor: '#596b96' }]}>
                <Text>{item.id}</Text>
                <Text>{item.testScore}</Text>
                <Text>{item.targetReached.toString()}</Text>
                <Text>{item.difference}</Text>
           </View>
         )} />
</View>
```

If the array is empty, I would set my array to be `["none"]`, and trying to display this causes the following error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.targetReached.toString`)

How do I conditionally render my `FlatList` in the way I want?

Comment: Why not have an empty array ?

Comment: `completedTests` gets data from Firebase Firestore, so for new users then it will be empty

Comment: The issue here is you have an item of type string "none", only option would be to check type of and decide component

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Please refer my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting your array to "none" use this approach

```
<FlatList
    data={completedTests}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    ListEmptyComponent={<Text>None</Text>}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
           <View style={[styles.scoreOverview, { backgroundColor: '#596b96' }]}>
                <Text>{item.id}</Text>
                <Text>{item.testScore}</Text>
                <Text>{item.targetReached.toString()}</Text>
                <Text>{item.difference}</Text>
           </View>
         )} />
```

The [ListEmptyComponent](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#listemptycomponent) would render when the array you supply is empty

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work in what you are trying to do there ...

```
       <View>
        {
        completedTests[0] !== "none" ? (<FlatList
            data={completedTests}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
                   <View style={[styles.scoreOverview, { backgroundColor: '#596b96' }]}>
                        <Text>{item.id}</Text>
                        <Text>{item.testScore}</Text>
                        <Text>{item.targetReached.toString()}</Text>
                        <Text>{item.difference}</Text>
                   </View>
                 )} />) : (
<Text>None</Text>
    )
        }
        </View>
```

so you check the array content and if it's not the `["none"]` then you can render flatList else something else or nothing.

Comment: This does work at showing "None" where I want it to, but for some reason it completely freezes my app and makes it unresponsive unless I reload it. Any idea as to why?

Comment: are there any errors or warnings in your console ? @KLG

Comment: No errors or warnings whatsoever, the entire app just doesn't respond to anything I touch on the screen.

Comment: change your approach then, like @Guruparan said.